# why does RxJS retryWhen operator completes with its inner Observable?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

Why does `retryWhen` completes with its inner Observable?

Imagine that we need to make maximum **3** attempts to fetch data. And, for example sake, our **3rd attempt will definitely work**. So I try the following:

```js
// ...
retryWhen(errors$ =>
  errors$.pipe(
    take(3)
  )
)
```

Which will make 3 attempts, but will immediately **complete after 3rd error**, together with its inner observable. Even if our 3rd attempt was about to give us results.

An illustration:

[image: retryWhen completing with inner Observable]

[Run this example](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/11d9457e53282dbe9eff1d48d58db24d)

**UPDATED NOTE:** Probably, to properly limit retry attempts — we should [use `switchMap` to switch based on index to `of(error)` or to `throwError(error)`](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/2bcd4bb2ee9be92de22d65b39c5ec813).

For me this behavior was unexpected: as I though inner observable will only trigger a retry. And once it notifies about a retry -- it's job is done, and we don't care if it completes.

So this question is rather theoretical then practical:

What was the reasoning behind this particular behavior? And what are its advantages?

**NOTE:** Its not an issue, operator behaves as described

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable with the
>   exception of an error. If the source Observable calls error, this
>   method will emit the Throwable that caused the error to the Observable
>   returned from notifier. **If that Observable calls complete or error
>   then this method will call complete or error on the child
>   subscription.** Otherwise this method will resubscribe to the source
>   Observable.

Comment: I think it needs to react to `complete` notification from its inner Observable because if it didn't then there would be no way to stop retrying. However, I agree with you that it's counter intuitive that `retryWhen` completes immediately after receiving `complete` from the inner Observable and it doesn't wait what the source Observable does. I don't even think there's any easy way around it. I'll try to think about it maybe I'll have some good idea in the morning...

Comment: @martin Well, I though that we could complete outer observable when we need to, e.g. `retryWhen(...).takeUntil(...)`. As I see it, we only need to care about inner observable errors.